virt-manager Guest does not grab key combinations
I am trying to switch from VirtualBox, I have little experiance with libvirt. So far I am managing to replicate most features, but I cannot get the guest to grab the keyboard shortcuts using Alt or Super.
Those key combinations are sent to both the guest and the host. I am testing on both guest and host arch based systems at the moment.
I read on the ArchWiki about edev and some manual editing. I have not tried any of it yet because for what I could read, support is supposed to be built-in, and I find it overly complicated for a behavior that I am used to have as a default all VM guests (VmWare or VirtualBox).
I have spice-vdagent installed on my guests, and I could not find any additional settings that seem related in virt-manager.
Thanks for your time.
